# want to display not matching records from table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have records like below

```
Table1
id |  123 456 345 789

Table2
name| 123.abc 345.jkl
```

Now I want to display only id i.e (`456,789` likewise)

Please need assistance

Comment: What have you tried ? SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: So, you want the `id` from `table1` with no matching name in `table2`? What is a "match" - a name that includes the `id` to the left of the dot, and anything to the right of the dot? Is the dot required? (So if the `name` was `123` instead of `123.abc`, would that still be a match?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MINUS` . If `id` is  `VARCHAR2` field, `TO_CHAR` on id is not required. `SUBSTR`, `INSTR` are used to extract characters before the first "."

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(id) ID
FROM   table1
MINUS
SELECT SUBSTR(NAME, 1, INSTR(NAME, '.') - 1) 
FROM   table2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this. The "matching" is done in the subquery (in the NOT EXISTS condition in the WHERE clause). It is written assuming that the requirement is that "name" matches "id" when "name" is the "id" followed by a period followed by at least one more character. If the period is not mandatory, or if it is but it may be the last character of the name, the query can be easily modified to accommodate that requirement.

```
with
  table1 ( id ) as (
    select '123' from dual union all
    select '456' from dual union all
    select '345' from dual union all
    select '789' from dual
  ),
  table2 ( name ) as (
    select '123.abc' from dual union all
    select '345.jkl' from dual
  )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select id
from   table1 t1
where  not exists ( 
                    select name
                    from   table2
                    where  name like t1.id || '._%'
       )
;

 ID
---
456
789
```